# Swift can throw in `if let` blocks?

Tags: swift, generics, exception, swift4

Wrote this simple `getJson` wrapper:

```
func getJson<T>(path: String) -> T? {
    let url = URL(string: path)
    let session = URLSession.shared
    var obj: T?
    if let usableUrl = url {
        let task = session.dataTask(with: usableUrl,
          completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in        // # <-- this line
            if let data = data {
                if let stringData = String(
                      data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    obj = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: json)
                }
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }
    return obj
}
```

But I get this error about my `completionHandler`:

> Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(_, _, _) throws -> ()' to non-throwing function type '(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void'

On a related note, this is 3 layers of `if` statements, can they be flattened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has quite a lot of problems apart from the throwing issue. Like you noticed, the many nested ifs make it hard to read, but mainly, it returns your `obj` variable before waiting for the asynchronous network call and thus wouldn't produce the results you're expecting.

Here's how I would start rewriting it.

```
func getJson<T: Decodable>(path: String, completion: @escaping (T?) -> () ) {
    guard let url = URL(string: path) else {
        return
    }

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if let data = data {
            do {
                let obj = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
                completion(obj)
            } catch {
                completion(nil)
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}

// usage example:

struct Foo: Decodable {
    let bar: Int
}

getJson(path: "http://example.com") { (obj: Foo?) in
    if let foo = obj {
        // processs data
    } else {
        // an error occurred
    }
}
```

Comment: This is from my first custom Swift project. Hmm, so that `@escaping` thing is just a callback? - Ohh I see, so this function doesn't return anything, and this is like how I handle async in JavaScript. - Thanks: +1 & accept

Comment: Where I am in my debugging: `func get() -> ActualType? {
        HttpClient().getJson(path: api) { (actualType: ActualType) in
            print(actualType.getString())
            return nil
        }
    }`

Comment: Thanks. Hmm, that's exactly what I was debugging. Just tried running again and the errors disappeared (had tried clean + build; but err remained then :\). Anyway, it works now

Comment: Were you possibly missing the `?` in the closure parameter's type?

Comment: Yeah, that might've been it. Was a weird error though. Anyway, now I need to bring this HTTP call back into the main thread somehow to resolve: >This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.

Comment: That's easily done, but not in the scope of this question - ask a new one

Answer (score 0):

Your completion handler uses a try keyword that throws an exception when it fails. That's why you get an error. Completion handler expects a non throwing method as the message error says.

You need to catch the error by using :

```
do {
    obj = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: json)
} catch {
    print("error") // Write here what you want to do if decoder fails.
}
```